# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing } after property list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider

I have to search price range(min_price & max_price) from two columns(regular_price & sale_price) but unable to get values from both columns.

```
<script src="{{ asset('themes/js/jquery-ui.js') }}"></script>
<script>
$( function() {
    $("#amount" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: {{ $min_price }},
        max: {{ $max_price }},
        values: [ 0, {{ $max_price }} ],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).val( " تومان " + ui.values[ 0 ] + " -  تومان " + ui.values[ 1 ] );
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'html',
            url: '',
            data: 'amount',
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    }
    $( "#amount" ).val( " تومان " + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
        " -  تومان " + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
});
</script>
```

I see this error

[image: error]

Comment: There is a bit of mess in your curly braces/parentheses

Comment: How do I fix it? And I send the slider to ajax?

Comment: I strongly suggest you to use a code editor (like Visual Studio Code) that can give you immediate visual feedback about uncorrectly closed brackets (and much more support of course)

Answer (score 0):

Your `slide:` property is missing a bracket.

Change the code to:

```
<script src="{{ asset('themes/js/jquery-ui.js') }}"></script>
<script>
$( function() {
    $("#amount" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: {{ $min_price }},
        max: {{ $max_price }},
        values: [ 0, {{ $max_price }} ],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).val( " تومان " + ui.values[ 0 ] + " -  تومان " + ui.values[ 1 ] )};
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'html',
            url: '',
            data: 'amount',
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
 }
    $( "#amount" ).val( " تومان " + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
        " -  تومان " + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
);
</script>
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Iwt5.png I get this error and in here

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bt4S.png

Comment: I have made an edit can you check if the changes work?